# JSoup Searching for element

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I was wondering if someone could help me navigate a html page with jsoup.

Probably the biggest issue I am having is using the .data() function. I am trying to pull the current weather when you google search "weather". Right now my code looks like:

```
try{ Connection formPage = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=weather&oq=weather&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j69i60j0l3.3806j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8");
     formPage.timeout(1000)
        .data("action", "wob_t")
        //.data("q", "Calgary")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36")
        .execute();
     Document getformPage = formPage.get();
     System.out.println(getformPage.getElementsByClass("wob_t"));
   }catch(Exception exception){
      System.exit(0);
   }
```

I believe I have everything except the correct navigation for .data(). Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain little bit more what is your expected result and what the problem is? The code you provided does return an output, what is missing?

Comment: The output doesn't return anything. The code itself works, but the information in the data function doesn't correctly follow the google search's html code.

Comment: Ok, for me it works, means I get temperature and other stuff printed. Have you checked how returned document looks like for you? Try 'System.out.println(getformPage.html())', and post your output.

Comment: Also, since you are using GET method setting data for the connection is the same as adding parameters to your URL, i.e. appending &action=wob_t. You can check it by printing System.out.println(formPage.request().url());

Comment: I see now, I get given temperatures. Is there a way to get just the current weather to show, like 35 degrees?

Comment: I have updated it so it now returns a null value. is there a way to fix this?