# Jsoup Weather Tool

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I asked a question regarding this earlier, I am closer to my main goal, but still not where I want things to be. My current code:

```
       try{
Connection formPage = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=weather&oq=weather&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j69i60j0l3.3806j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8");
formPage.timeout(1000)
    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36")
    .execute();
            Document getformPage = formPage.get();
            //Element getformPage = formPage.getElementById("wob_t");
            System.out.println(getformPage.getElementById("wob_t"));
           //System.out.println(formPage.request().url());


        }catch(Exception exception){
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Returns a null expression. I want it to give the current weather. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is it correct id which you are passing , i think it should be `getformPage.getElementById("wob_tm")`

Comment: AFAIK, Google uses only JavaScript to display this. Therefore, JSoup is pretty much useless. You should better look into Selenium

Comment: @r3dst0rm have you checked the page source of the `weather page` provided by google, all the details which OP needs is present inside that and it can be easily scrapped/parsed using Jsoup. Jsoup will read all the details which are present in the page source :)

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh As I just wanted to know what we get from the OP's URL, I used `try.jsoup.org` and fetched the given URL there. There is clearly no result HTML as we would get it in the browser to scrape the weather information.

Comment: @CalebDunham You have replaced method  `getformPage.getElementsByClass("wob_t")` with `getformPage.getElementById("wob_t"))` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196106/jsoup-searching-for-element

Comment: There are no elements with id `wob_t` in html. You can either get all elements with class `wob_t`, or get each data separately by getting `getformPage.getElementById("wob_ws")` for wind speed,  `getformPage.getElementById("wob_hm")` for humidity etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going for google search results, you can directly fetch the details from `https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/18.60,73.71` where `18.60,73.71` will be the coordinates of the location you want the details.

[image: Google search result]

[image: weather.com]

Inside that you can use the **selector tag** `div.today_nowcard-temp` for the temperature and similarly for other details as well.

As earlier suggested by @r3dst0rm the details are not coming into the document which you are retrieving from the google search page tried on https://try.jsoup.org/

Where the details which you need are not present, hence you have to try the other ways to get your desired result, in which i am suggesting one.

Comment: That's one neat possible solution. And should probably be the accepted answer. Got my +1 for accessing the source instead of "copying" from Google.